# How to pass big length of encrypted string url in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass the encrypted string with URL but it's giving me error

> 404 page can't found.

URL sample:

> http://localhost/elearn/join/video/call/for/lecture/6fc1a5f5a35741988051cca196ce8609/talkme/0066fc1a5f5a35741988051cca196ce8609IABaKWU/xYxlYJKs7nVS845xc9d0YcRLJJhdUEdpTzhDs85c2l0AAAAAEADgyGnmqB4dXwEAAQCmHh1f

How can I succeed in accessing the specific route?

how to increase the encrypted character length in URL using laravel?

Comment: please show us your current route

Comment: Laravel's encrypter uses OpenSSL to provide AES-256 and AES-128 encryption. Why you want to increase character length?

Comment: Please pass the same parameter in route.